# VCL Forms Application

Tags: c++, class, include, c++builder, vcl

I have written some C++ Classes for a console application.

How do I use these classes in a VCL Forms Application. I am using C++ Builder XE2.

I have added the .h and .cpp files via the Project->Add to project. Do I need to write an include statement? If so, where do I do this?

I tried placing the include statements at the top of the .cpp file, yet I get the following error: Unable to open include file.

I have the .h and .cpp files in the same directory as the Forms project.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a quick hack. It worked for me.

Move the entire class you wrote from the `.CPP` file in to the `.H` file. Move everything.

In the .`CPP` file of the vcl form, `form1.cpp`, include the `.H` file that contains the C++ Classes.

or you could just paste parts of the class methods into `form1.h` so they become part of the    `public ref class form1{};` class all together instead of having two different classes clash, the form1  class and your class.